# How do I write a bash script which runs a program until it senses signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, bash, segmentation-fault

Learning C-pointers and I am convinced that a program which ran successfully yesterday involving pointers to a struct core dumped on me today without me even touching it, at least that is what I believe. Is it reasonable? I do not allocate memory dynamically.
Changed it today but hower but how do I write a bash script
which restarts the program until it returns with a segmentation fault.
Maybe also count how many times it can execute the program until the event occurs?
How do I sense the SIGSEGV signal?

Comment: You'd probably be better served by posting your C program here so we can show you what you did wrong in it.

Comment: " program which ran successfully yesterday involving pointers to a struct core dumped on me today". Those are the common symptoms in code with undefined behaviour. Usually caused by invalid memory access or memory corruptions. And it doesn't require dynamic memory to occur. Show your code if you need help finding the problem. Alternatively if developing in Linux then use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you find memory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect this by checking its exit status. Here's `man bash`:

```
   The return value of a simple command is its exit status,  or  128+n  if
   the command is terminated by signal n.
```

Since `kill -l` shows `SIGSEGV` as signal 11, you can therefore run the program until it exits with 139:

```
until ./yourprogram; [ $? -eq 139 ]; do printf '.'; done
```

If this is `yourprogram.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  if(getpid()%100 == 0 ) {
    char* ptr = 1;
    *ptr = 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You get a result like this (one dot per non-segfault invocation):

```
............................Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Incredible useful script. Program that I though was rock solid was proved be <= trash. Thought that I understood pointers. Back on zero -again :-)